# Other than $PATH, how are terminal commands added in OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables

When I `echo $PATH` in terminal, I see the only software added is MySQL, some Python stuff, and HLA:

Following are the contents of `.bash_profile` which modifies the `$PATH` system variable presumably during startup.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/usr/hla"
export hlalib="$HOME/usr/hla/hlalib"
export hlainc="$HOME/usr/hla/include"
export hlatemp="$HOME/usr/hla/tmp"


# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 4.1.1 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

If Java has no presence on my `$PATH` variable in OSX, how does terminal find the `java` and `javac` commands? What other feature of the OSX operating system is used to provide command line options such as git, Homebrew, and the aforementioned Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see where the command is located by using `which java`. It gives you the location. By doing this, you can see that commands like `java`,`git` etc are present in `bin`. You can directly copy executables to `bin` folder and use it as a command.